# Is it possible to see the visited websites with Linksys WAG54GS

Tags: logging, dsl-modem

There is this Wireless ADSL Gateway/Modem at work (Linksys WAG54GS), I was wondering if someone at work, or system engineer here can be able to see the visited website URLs?

[This is the modem's website by the way.](http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/gateways/WAG54GS)

Comment: Did you enable logging? If it exists you may have a chance but you'll need to learn your own router (the link you cite has the manual on, did you find anything in there)?

Answer (score 1):

If the router is set up to keep *very* detailed logs, you *might* get the IP addresses to which connections were made. I wouldn't count on it, that is a extremely paranoid configuration. It is possible to intercept traffic and thus reconstruct web browsing history.

Your best bet is to look at the machine, web browsers keep history and cache last sites visited.

Comment: @BonusKun In addition to this, If you want to implement this in the future, take a look at [Snort](http://www.snort.org/)